# How to Disable Mouse Edge Flip on Linux Mint Cinnamon 2.8

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon, workspaces

I have been suffering for the unexpected disapperance on Cinnamon 2.8 of the `Enable/Disable Edge Flip` option between workspaces with the mouse, I found really really annoying that every time I would pass and leave my mouse pointer in the edge of the screen it will start switching workspaces and I had to press the `Escape Key` to exit from this behaviour. Frustration set in and after a while I invested a fair amount of time seeking for a solution, I found it buried deep deep in some internet forum.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal enter this command.

> gsettings set org.cinnamon enable-edge-flip false

Hope this will save someone some frustration!

Regards.
EN